# Installing matplotlib through setuptools install_requires

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, setuptools, install-requires

I have been trying to install matplotlib through install_requires and it has been failing with error: unexpected html page found...

When I just try to install it regularly through pip it seems to work fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this kind of issue with install_requires.  I would like setup.py to handle these issues.  I had a similar problem with numpy failing with Python.h problems, but then a regular pip install fixed that as well.

Comment: Why is your question titled 'installing through pip' if that works fine?

Comment: can you provide the full error message?